# How to search for a row entry in a pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rows, data-manipulation

Do you know how to search for a row data entry in a pandas DataFrame? And ideally search for a partial row entry in the dataframe.

Just like if I had a row entry:

```
row_entry = ['ven', 'lar', 'cin', 'por']
```

And a dataframe rows_df:

```
rows_df =
             value1        value2       value3       value4      value5
14              foo           fir          tar          har    0.110000
15              bar           der          ars           go    0.510000
16              gal           der          ben          den    0.310000
17              ven           lar          cin          por    0.140000
18               go           bun          por         fran    0.560000
```

And the 17th line would be selected. This without using a series of if clauses.

```
result = 
             value1        value2       value3       value4      value5
17              ven           lar          cin          por    0.140000
```

What I tried (and it works) is:

```
rows_df[(rows_df['value1'] == 'ven') 
      & (rows_df['value2'] == 'lar')
      & (rows_df['value3'] == 'cin')
      & (rows_df['value4'] == 'por')]
```

Ideally I wouldn't need to specify which are the column names, or to specify the values order. I'm thinking in something like the `.isin()` clause but done with each row instead of column.

Just like (which doesn't work):

```
df.loc[df.isin(some_values, axis=1)]
```

Also looked at the `iloc` and `loc` functions, but maybe I'm loosing something.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
df[np.isin(df, ['ven', 'lar', 'cin', 'por']).all(axis = 1)]
```

Comment: This approach is more flexible to determine `row_entry` when values in different columns are irrelevant. `df[np.isin(df, ['cin', 'lar', 'por', 'ven']).all(axis=1)]` gives you the same result.

Comment: It just worked for me when I set the columns to be compared. It was supposed to happen? `rows_df[np.isin(rows_df[rows_df.columns[:4]], row_entry).all(axis = 1)]`